# After Effects: Set Alpha/Matte to hdr layer without clamping the values to 0-1 range

Tags: after-effects

I have a .hdr sequence as well as a .tga sequence. the .tga sequence contains the alpha channel to be used for the .hdr sequence.

The problem is that if I apply the alpha channel to my hdr sequence using Set Matte or Set Channel, then the color values of my hdr sequence get clamped to 0-1.

How can I mask my hdr sequence without losing the hdr range?

using After Effects CS5

Answer (score 1):

Okay, [this tutorial](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/After_Effects_32-bit_Workflow_In-Depth/) answered my question and provides a workaround.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thank you!

Comment: I second the motion!